# MAPI Outlook History/Change Log

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, mapi

Is there a way to see the changes to an 'AppointmentItem' through MAPI/Outlook?  So, for example, if a meeting was re-scheduled and the category changed as well, is it possible to see what exactly changed on the Appointment and when?

I can pull all current information and use fields such as CreationTime, BusyStatus, etc (I am using win32com in Python).  However, if I want to go back and see what was the original state of the meeting and what was changed, does anyone know how I would do that?  I don't see anything so far in the Microsoft Docs on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_members.aspx

I guess ideally there would be a field such as 'ChangeLog' that would tell you what/when field(s) changed from something, to something, and a timestamp.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such thing.
There are some "original" properties stored on the appointment, but nothing like what you want. Take a look at an appointment with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) (I am its author) - click IMessage button.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an Exchange mailbox, and it hasn't been [disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.data.directory.management.mailbox.calendarversionstoredisabled(v=exchg.150).aspx), you can use the Calendar Version Store. The Exchange team blog has a good [writeup](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/01/17/exchange-2010-calendar-repair-assistant.aspx) on a number of aspects of calendar data. You can query the Calendar Version Store using the powershell command [Get-CalendarDiagnosticLog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638102(v=exchg.141).aspx), or if you're feeling more hardcore, you can look at the store directly using [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com). The Calendar Version Store folder lives directly off the root container of the mailbox. Make sure you're online and not in cached mode, as the data is not in the offline cache.